# How do you add schema annotations for EF Core in a Portable Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, data-annotations, portable-class-library

For a project I am working on we have written a Portable PCL to contain models and other code that will be shared between multiple projects. The Data Access Layer is in another project in the solution, but I would like to use EF data annotations in the PCL to match our current convention. I have data annotations in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace working just fine, but System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema annotations are not found.

The reference is added, and I have even tried re-adding EF to the PCL, but I haven't had any luck. I read another post where they ran into an issue using both namespaces simultaneously, but I can't even get .Schema working by itself.

Here is an example of what my code looks like:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema; //VS shows that this is not being used

namespace Shared.Models.User
{
   public class BaseUser
   {
      [JsonProperty("id")]
      [Key]
      [Column("UserId", Order = 1)] // ***ColumnAttribute not found  
      public Guid Id { get; set; } 
      ...
      [JsonProperty("fullName")]
      [NotMapped] // ***NotMappedAttribute not found
      public string FullName => String.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
      ...
   }
}
```

The PCL is targeting .Net 4.5, .Net Core 1.0, UWP, and Xamarin platforms. In the Nuget Package manager it shows that both of the before-mentioned namespaces have been added to the project, but they do not show up in the solution explorer. I have tried cleaning the project, building, and restoring packages but still nothing. I don't see any reason that this shouldn't work in a Portable PCL, but am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Does installing the `System.ComponentModel.Annotations` NuGet package help? If not, they may just not be available on that type of project.

Comment: No, that doesn't help at all. That's the one that is working right now, but the System.ComponentModel.Annotations.Schema is the one that I'm having problems with. That's what I am thinking as well, but wanted to see if anyone else has ran into this.

Comment: Confirmed. You need to target at lest [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) 1.3 (no equivalent PCL profile)